# Back button don't appear in navigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIViewController, with a navigationController, and I hide the back button. This viewController push a other UIViewController, and in the viewDidLoad of this new viewController, I do:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = FALSE;
```

But the backbutton doesn't happear. Why? And this don't work when I pass to the new Xcode version for iOS 4.2, because in the latest version, it all works well.

Comment: Can you post a) the code you use to push the view controller and b) `viewDidLoad:` in your new view controller.

Answer (score 8):

Is there a title for the previous navigationController (on the navigation bar)? Sometimes, if there is no title, the first back button is hidden automatically.

Comment: This is the "correct" answer - the iOS 3.x is "buggy"/inconsistent with later iOS version about this. Still with iOS 3.x the back button is invisible, but if you try to tap where it should be, it actually brings you back. This kind of says that this was really a interface glitch/bug in iOS 3.x...

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Interface Builder, check the Navigation Item object inside the View Controller that is attached to the Navigation Controller.. For clarity, in IB:

Navigation Controller || Something View Controller || Navigation Item

In Inspector on the Attributes tab, there should be a Text Field named "Back Button". Make sure this has something in it such as "Back".

After it's listed for the first ViewController, it will propagate through the stack.

Comment: You can also set the back button title programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same problem running iOS 4.2. The back button would refuse to appear. Upon autoroating to landscape, it then appears. My solution was to do the following - This fixed the problem...or should we say its a workaround ;)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    checkHolder.image = anImage;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem in iOS 4.2 and your hack fixed it. iOS 4.3 through 5.0 does not need this hack. I have not tested on iOS less than 4.2, so I can't tell if this problem is exclusive to 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with Syoleen , one should have a title text set to the navigationController, You can set the title to @" " (thats a space there in-between) if you don't want it to be shown but still have it active.

Comment: I found this trick the hard way by mistake. However I would not suggest using it because the user loses the intuitiveness of the iphone interface.