# Back button does not appear in navigation bar until you rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have three view controllers: `A` -> `B` -> `C` managed by a navigation controller. `A` is a transient view controller. It asks the server for something. If the server says everyhing is OK, then `A` pushes `B` onto the stack. `B` must hide the back button because I don't want users to manually go back to `A`.

```
// B view controller
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.title = @"B";
}
```

`B` then pushes `C` onto the stack when the user taps a table cell.

```
// B view controller
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    C *c = [[C alloc] 
        initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped
    ];
    [self.navigationController 
        pushViewController:c 
        animated:YES
    ];
    [c release];
}
```

.

```
// C view controller
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
    self.title = @"C";
}
```

If all goes well, the flow should look like this:

```
-------------    -------------    -------------
|_____A_____|    |_____B ____|    | <B|__ C___|
|           | => |           | => |           |
| loading...|    |   cells   |    |   detail  |
|           |    |           |    |           |
-------------    -------------     -----------
```

For some reason, `C` does not show a back button to go back to `B` *until* I rotate the device. Once rotated, the back button appears in all orientations. The problem seems to stem from `B` hiding the back button and `C` trying to reveal it again, because If I don't let `B` hide it, I don't have this problem. So how do I get C to show the back button without forcing the user to rotate the device like a monkey?

## Update

- Broken on two different Verizon iPhone 4 both on iOS 4.2.10
- Fine on AT&T iPhone 3GS on iOS 5.0
- Fine on AT&T iPhone 4 on iOS 4.3

Comment: Why leave A on the stack, then?  If you don't ever want to go back to A, you might want to take it out of the navigation controller.

Comment: sounds like the drawing routine for the navigation bar is not called for some reason, and turning the device is probably triggering the drawing. You could try calling [super viewDidLoad] after setting the hideBackButton property, or maybe re-showing the navigation bar in viewDidLoad with [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:false animated:false] - maybe that triggers the drawing, too.

Comment: I keep A on the stack because sometimes I like to pop to the root and run A again.

Comment: you could also try to show the back button in controller B just before switching to controller C

Comment: @TheEye I put `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO` in `B` view controller's `viewWillDisappear`and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: a prime example of apples broken controller implementations and not acknowlidging bugs publicly. See the iPhone Landscape FAQ here on SO for a host of similar issues.

Comment: You could display A as a modal controller (or other outside of the nav controller). (Used for login right?) Then use a nav controller for B and C only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching I found this solution for iPhone 4.2 (since you posted that it works on later versions) on some old forum post.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { 
                     [super viewDidLoad];
                     self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; 
                   }

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
                                       [super viewDidAppear:animated];
                                       self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO; 
                                    }
```

Mayhaps this will help you out.
(Check this out: [Back button don't appear in navigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281063/back-button-dont-appear-in-navigationcontroller))

Comment: This does the trick. Conceptually what this does is trick the iOS into thinking it wants to continue hiding the back button. Then once the view is drawn on the screen, it sneaks in the back button again. I can see a split second were the button is not there and then it's plastered on top. It's something stupid that has to be done for iOS 4.2. I haven't tested on older iOS, so I don't know if the problem is exclusive to 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put your code like this for C

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work (after correcting your spelling error "viViewDidAppear").

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once and solved it by giving B's navigation item a title

```
// B view controller
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"What you want C's back button to say";
    self.title = @"B";
}
```

If you don't want the title to appear in B you can set B's navigationItem's titleView to an empty view. About the titleView property:

> If this property value is nil, the navigation item’s title is displayed in the center of the navigation bar when the receiver is the top item. If you set this property to a custom title, it is displayed instead of the title. This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil.

Comment: This didn't work. Still, I have to rotate to get the back button to appear. The button will say "B", not "What you wan't C's back button to say".

Comment: What does the navigation item tell you its backBarButtonItem is when it's invisible and shouldn't be? You could also look at the - (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated method of UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;` into the init method or anywhere before the pushViewController call.

ViewDidLoad is called when you ask the controller for the view for the first time, that means, it is probably called from `[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES]`. But note that the navigation bar is not part of your view, it is created and handled by `UINavigationController`, so basically it can exist and be drawn even before viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear is called. If you update navigation bar there, it doesn't get actually repainted.

Edit 1: Revisited after reading the documentation for `[UIViewController navigationItem]`

> You should avoid tying the creation of bar button items in your navigation item to the creation of your view controller’s view. The navigation item of a view controller may be retrieved independently of the view controller’s view. For example, when pushing two view controllers onto a navigation stack, the topmost view controller becomes visible, but the other view controller’s navigation item may be retrieved in order to present its back button. To ensure the navigation item is configured, you can override this property and add code to load the bar button items there or load the items in your view controller’s initialization code.

Edit 2: Revisited after reading the comment that my solution does not work. Working code (iOS 5, ARC):

```
//
//  TestAppDelegate.m
//  NavigationTest
//
//  Created by Sulthan on 10/25/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 StackOverflow. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

@interface TestAppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UINavigationController* navigationScreen;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIViewController* screen1;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIViewController* screen2;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIViewController* screen3;

@end

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window = window_;
@synthesize navigationScreen = navigationScreen_;
@synthesize screen1 = screen1_;
@synthesize screen2 = screen2_;
@synthesize screen3 = screen3_;

- (UIViewController*)createTestScreenWithLabel:(NSString*)label {
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UIViewController* screen = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    screen.view = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    screen.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    ((UILabel*) screen.view).textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    ((UILabel*) screen.view).text = label;

    return screen;
}

- (void)pushThirdScreen {
    if (!self.screen3) {
        self.screen3 = [self createTestScreenWithLabel:@"Screen 3"];
        self.screen3.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
    }

    [self.navigationScreen pushViewController:self.screen3 animated:YES];
}

- (void)pushSecondScreen {
    self.screen2 = [self createTestScreenWithLabel:@"Screen 2"];
    self.screen2.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    UIBarButtonItem* button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Go"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(pushThirdScreen)];

    self.screen2.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;

    [self.navigationScreen pushViewController:self.screen2 animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.screen1 = [self createTestScreenWithLabel:@"Screen 1"];

    self.navigationScreen = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.screen1];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationScreen.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self performSelector:@selector(pushSecondScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Edit 3: Revisited after noticing that you are speaking mainly about iOS 4.2. I can't currently test it on any iOS 4.2 but I know about a possible workaround. You can always hide the navigation bar in your UINavigationController and just put a separate navigation bar into each screen. You will have absolute control over them and you can even edit them in Interface Builder.

Comment: Didn't work. I put this in the C view controller: `-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style { self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO; return [super initWithStyle:style]; }`

Comment: Oh my god. [super initWithStyle:style] must be always the first thing you call in your init method. Before you call it, there is no navigationItem you can set up.

Comment: Putting the super call in the beginning didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your class C:

```
-(id) init
 {
   [super init];
   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
 }
```

Comment: I don't initialize my C controller with `init`. I initialize it with `initWithStyle`. @Sulthan already suggested a similar fruitless approach.

Comment: Did you try putting self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO; before your pushViewController ?

Comment: Yeah, all that does is make B's back button appear. I need C to show it's back button.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for your back button situation but I know that when I use a custom back button I need to set the custom back button on the alloc'd item before I push it (not self like the post above).  Hopefully it will work for your situation as well - worth a try.

In other words, try:

```
// B view controller
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    C *c = [[C alloc] 
        initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    // *** set on c's navigationItem (not self) before you push
    [[c navigationItem] setHidesBackButton: NO];

    [self.navigationController 
        pushViewController:c 
        animated:YES
    ];

    [c release];
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. I also tried setting both B and C to hide the back button before pushing C. I saw B's back button appear as C was sliding in. C still did not have a back button.

Comment: OK - worth a try.  Sorry couldn't help more.